# Add custom field to Adminhtml form and fill data (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2

I need to add Entity_id to Rating Edit Form (Stores -> Rating -> Edit Rating).
I try to achieve this with plugin

Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab\Form">
    <plugin name="add_entity_type_rating_form" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab\Form" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

And class Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab\Form:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab;

class Form
{
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab\Form $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $fieldset = $form->getElement('rating_form');
            if ($fieldset) {
                $fieldset->addField(
                    'entity_id',
                    'text',
                    [
                        'name' => 'entity_id',
                        'label' => __('Entity Type'),
                        'title' => __('Entity Type'),
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

On the backend I can see filed 'Entity Type', but it has no value
[image: rating_edit_form]

How should I pass data to this filed (entity_id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Smirnov I just solved a similar issue, what you need to do is set the values to the form again in your plugin function. The result should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Form
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab\Form $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @return \Closure $proceed
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Edit\Tab\Form $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $ratingData = $this->registry->registry('rating_data');
            $fieldset = $form->getElement('rating_form');
            if ($fieldset) {
                $fieldset->addField(
                    'entity_id',
                    'text',
                    [
                        'name' => 'entity_id',
                        'label' => __('Entity Type'),
                        'title' => __('Entity Type'),
                    ]
                );
            }

            if ($ratingData) {
                $form->setValues($ratingData);
            }
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you to solve your requirement. Best.

Comment: This is working for me also